# Move entire dataset from one google project to another google project without data

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, copy

as part of code deployment to production, we need to copy all tables from a big query dataset to production environment. However, the UI option or the bq command line option is moving the data too . How do I just move all the BIG QUERY tables at once from non prod to prod environment without data??
Kindly suggest?

Comment: A possible workaround: you first create the dataset in the destination project and then run CREATE TABLE new_project.dataset.xx AS SELECT * FROM old_project.dataset.xx WHERE 1=0. You also need to make sure to specify the partition field. This works well for datasets where there are just a few tables, for larger datasets I believe you can script this operation in Python or whatever else you use.

Answer (score 1):

posting my comment as an answer:

I don't know about any way how to achieve what you want directly, but there is a possible workaround:

You first need to create the dataset in the destination project and then run `CREATE TABLE new_project.dataset.xx AS SELECT * FROM old_project.dataset.xx WHERE 1=0`.

You also need to make sure to specify the partition field. This works well for datasets where there are just a few tables, for larger datasets you can script this operation in Python or whatever else you use.